# How to DRY up on SASS transitions with multiple elements?

Tags: css, sass, transition

I have the following code which turns out to generate a lot of transition statements in the compiled CSS. I am wondering how to better improve the code structure to take care of multiple transitions in a page.

```
.container
    +outer-container
    max-width: $desktop-breakpoint
    margin: 0 auto
    position: relative
    padding-top: 1.8em
    padding-bottom: 1.8em
    +background(url('images/button-action.svg') right 10% center no-repeat)
    +transition($quick-ease)
    &:hover
        +background(url('images/button-action.svg') right 8% center no-repeat)
        padding-top: 2em
        padding-bottom: 2em
        h3, p.subtitle
            margin-left: 5%
            +transition($quick-ease)
        +transition($quick-ease)
    h3
        color: #FFFFFF
        margin: 0
        +transition($quick-ease)
    p.subtitle
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75)   
        letter-spacing: 1.8px
        margin: 0
        +transition($quick-ease)
```

Comment: Only adding a few more media queries and transition. I already feel like the performance is hit seriously.

Comment: Fine tuning working code is more appropriate for CodeReview.SE.  Also, there's not enough code here to get this to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using same css chunk on multiple elements, You can use `@extend` method of SASS.

What it will do is combine multiple selector to a single class.

**i.e:**

```
.animation{
    +transition($quick-ease);
}
h3{
    @extend .animation;
    /* Other CSS */
}
p.subtitle{
    @extend .animation;
    /* Other CSS */
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
.animation, h3, p.subtitle { /* animation css */ }
h3{ /* Other CSS */ }
p.subtitle{ /* Other CSS */ }
```

This way the transition css wont be added again and again in multiple selector instead just at one place in your generate SASS Cheers!

Comment: wonder how to gauge performance impact to each CSS transition / animation added.